# Update Telerik.DataAccess.Core 2015.1.225.1 Assemblies to most recent nuget package

Tags: nuget, telerik, .net-4.0

In our project we are using the the Telertik.DataAcess Assemblies shown here https://docs.telerik.com/data-access/developers-guide/deployment/visual-designer-deployment-consideration-operations-versioning.html (no nuget package).

I want to change everything to the most recent nuget package version (2018.x.x.x)

But there seems to be the namespaces from this assemply missing: Telerik.OpenAccess.Windows.dll.
I installed all nugte packages, but the "ObjectView" Class is still missing (part of Telerik.OpenAccess.Windows.dll).

I even tried to simply update the local assemblies, but there is no way to find the download page https://docs.telerik.com/data-access/installation/installation-install-data-access.html.
The shown page does not exits.

Did anybody try the same thing?